# Got TLS error trying to find package ABC at https://pub.dartlang.org

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I am using **Linux Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS**. I am creating a new **Flutter** project through git bash or terminal or from Visual Studio Code directly but gets an error which says:

> Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at
>   https://pub.dartlang.org

In Flutter Project's pubspec.yaml file I removed the line "**cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2**" in an attempt to resolve the issue but gets the same error on another package:

> Got TLS error trying to find package vector_math at
>   https://pub.dartlang.org

I've googled alot but couldn't find the right solution. Please do tell me the main cause of this issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

In the virtual machine, if your network working properly then check the date and time.

Comment: It was the time on my laptop thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For those who find their way to this answer via Google, here's what worked for me.  I am running Windows 10 x64 behind a corporate firewall (Zscaler), and my client uses a self-signed cert.  I eventually found [this Github comment](https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/2472#issuecomment-440462890) which described creating a system environment variable pointing to the self-signed cert.  Once I created the variable and restarted my command prompts, I was able to execute commands like `flutter pub get`.

Comment: where can I find tthe self-signed cert?

Comment: If you're working with or for an organization that uses a self-signed certificate, then there is likely someone who can help you get the cert.  I think it is also possible to find the certificate from your browser or thru openssl (https://superuser.com/q/97201/485406).

Answer (score 2):

You might need to setup a **self-signed certificate** to make it work correctly by setting the following enviroment variables:

On Linux:

> export DART_VM_OPTIONS="--root-certs-file={path.to.certificate.file}"

On Windows:

> set https_proxy="--root-certs-file={path.to.certificate.file}"

And in case you behind a **proxy**, please, also set the proxy variables:

Linux:

> export https_proxy="USERNAME:PASSWORD@hostname:port"

Windows:

> set https_proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@hostname:port

Comment: can you please explain how can i get this self signed certificate ?

Comment: Probably with you organization

Comment: Shouldn´t the first line on Windows be:
set DART_VM_OPTIONS="--root-certs-file={path.to.certificate.file}"

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was due to network permissions in our organization. I tried with some another network which has full access and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me
My example:
 1. Add dependency to *pubspec.yaml* file:

> *dependencies:
>
>     http:
>
>       git:
>
>         url: git://github.com/dart-lang/http.git*

2. When run cmd: flutter packages get. A error will appear at "http_parser" package
3. Now, download "http_parser" package from https://pub.dev/ (Version tab -> archive) and extract it to (if it not existed) %FLUTTER_HOME%.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org
4. Add new line in *pubspec.lock* file (at root folder of project)

> *http_parser:
>
>       dependency: transitive
>
>       description:
>
>         name: http_parser
>
>         url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
>
>       source: hosted
>
>       version: "3.1.3"*

5. Finally, run cmd: *flutter packages get* again!

see more: [Using Flutter Package](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)

Answer (score 0):

I did try many solutions but when I used a VPN it worked .. It seems to happen in some countries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ZScaler on Windows. Fortunately, I had the ZScaler root certificate sent over by someone from my corporate IT service desk team. The file name is ZscalerRootCA.cer
And then, I used the following value for DART_VM_OPTIONS

`--root-certs-file=C:\$PATH_TO_ZscalerRootCA.cer`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by executing the windows update trubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I was this problem too.

- I changed my network from Mobile data to WiFi.
- run Flutter doctor -v.
- I changed My VPN.

its was be ok.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your system's Date and Time are correct.