# Flutter doctor isn't going well

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor

After installing flutter sdk, android studio, and flutter plugin..

*1st I copied Android SDK tools manually because android studio didn't download it from web !!

*2nd When I tried to write "flutter doctor" in the command line, it didn't going well, and this is what actually happend.

```
PS C:\Users\MQ> flutter doctor -v
Got TLS error trying to find package node_preamble at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
Got TLS error trying to find package node_preamble at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
Got TLS error trying to find package node_preamble at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...  

                    |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Got TLS error trying to find package ABC at https://pub.dartlang.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362077/got-tls-error-trying-to-find-package-abc-at-https-pub-dartlang-org)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, I changed my network connection but I have had same issue. So to resolve this problem I changed flutter version to **1.22.6**, This version works for me and I didn't get these errors with this version.