# what the solution Creating project app .. -flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3wHe.png)

I dont't know, i try

Comment: Please, take the [tour] that you were offered when you posted, and see [ask].

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362077/got-tls-error-trying-to-find-package-abc-at-https-pub-dartlang-org

Answer (score 0):

This is because your system has internet connection protected with invalid or self-signed certificate.

Easy solution - check your system time, maybe wrong date.

If not, and you are using Windows, check if your system has self-signed certificate. You can try to install valid SSL root certificates (if it has) or use parameter DART_VM_OPTIONS=--root-certs-file=<your_cert>

In Linux certs also can be outdated, fresh certificates usually in system repo, just update your system.

At last, check your internet connection - if you using some type of proxi or firewall (or antivirus with built-in firewall) you can face this error.
Try to connect to internet directly or with different provider.